# Qualtrics - Pipe different text/value than the response given

Tags: qualtrics, piping

I want to pipe in information that is linked to the response in the previous question, but not a copy of the response.

Example: 
'You have 5 apples, how many do you want to give to the other participant?'
If a participant answered the multiple choice with '4', I want to give positive feedback 'You have decided to give 4 to the other participant, we are very happy about your generous behavior.'. If he answers with '1', the feedback is very similar, just a few words need to be changed 'You have decided to give 1 to the other participant, we are sad about your greedy behavior.'.

Do I need to use display logic to show specific feedback, or can I pipe in words (happy/sad) that are linked to a specific response (4/1)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the questions in separate blocks, you could create an embedded data variable, we'll call it 'addon', and set it based on the first question, then in the followup, you can pipe in 'addon' ${e://Field/addon} as your piped text instead.